# Parallax effect - should I use setInterval if I already use requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am working on a simple parallax effect for some elements on my side:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var offsetTop = $('.parallax').offset().top();
    var offsetBy = ((scrollTop - offsetTop) * .5).toFixed(0);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        $('.parallax').css('--parallax', offsetBy + 'px');
    }
});
```

This updates the position of the `.parallax` element like 60 times per second. I've read other tutorials and they suggest to use `setInterval` too. Is there a sense to do this since `window.requestAnimationFrame` already limits the number of time the animation is called?

Comment: This is opinion based so I'm voting to close it as such, but I personally do use both.  If you don't use `setInterval()` then the frame rate will just go up and up and up as computers get faster.  I use it to cap a maximum frame rate.  Let `requestAnimationFrame()` handle the minimum.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` asks the browser to pick the best time for updating render stuff. A nested `setTimeout` possible breaks out of this due the pushing the code to the end of the event loop. `setInterval` also do this but sound like a bad practice anyway as this forces the FPS where you might want to let the browser choose this.

The final verdict is probably opnitated and may be different for use cases but i'd say no, just use `requestAnimationFrame`, it's designed for stuff like this.

Comment: @Archer, do you mind to show me an example of your parallax?

Comment: And just to prove @Archer's point, here's my opinion: you should use `requestAnimationFrame()` for animations and measure exact time deltas to calculate positions. `requestAnimationFrame()` is much better optimized, `setInterval()` has an ugly habit of falling out of sync, and the documentation itself states that there's no guarantee it will actually run at the interval you specified. Also, you should probably just use a CSS animation in this case.

Comment: I would definitely say use `requestAnimationFrame` as it's very much related to drawing, so you want to optimise this as much as possible (also, browsers dont execute it when they are out of view, while Chrome stacks up the `intervals` and executes them rapidly when back in view, so it might have a lot of undesired side effects). Use `setInterval` for operations that aren't related to frames (like a check every five seconds instead of every frame).

Comment: @sdvnksv No - I've used it in other examples.  I use `setTimeout()` not `setInterval()`  (that was a mistake in my previous comment).  I'd have something like this... `function draw() { requestAnimationFrame(function() { // draw stuff; setTimeout(draw, 33)); }` <-- that would cap it to *about* 30fps.